# How do I convert SHP to TopoJSON using command lines on a Mac

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shapefile, topojson

I am attempting to make a data visualization map using SHP files from the Census Bureau. I wanted to convert the file to TOPOJSON without losing information associated with each path (i.e. keep the FIPS number associated with each path). I tried converting from SHP to JSON using MapShaper, but it seems like the FIPS info was lost along the way.

I went down a tutorial rabbit hole and found a bunch of examples of people using terminal commands to convert the SHP file. However, the documentation seems to be all over the place. Some are from 2010. Others are from 2017. The version of NPM I am using(6.14.4), the commands to output to JSON have changed I believe.

Could anyone point me to the latest documentation to convert SHP to TOPOJSON using command lines? Or if anyone knows a better way to convert, I am open to that, too. These maps will be used for the web, so the smaller TOPOJSON file, the better. I will eventually be using D3.js to project the map.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use mapshaper you can keep the data if you include the shape file's dbf with the shp and prj files.

Comment: That did the trick. Appreciate your help.